# Inserting Datetime into sqlite database iphone syntax error near time hours

Tags: iphone, sqlite, datetime

Inserting Datetime into sqlite database iphone syntax error near time hours
My query is given

```
UPDATE Orders SET Toal_Price = 33.33,Date_of_Submit=2013-04-12 15:34:16 ,Status=1 WHERE OrderID=2
```

Showing error:

near "15": syntax error

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, such timestamps are strings.

You have for format them like this:

```
UPDATE Orders
SET Toal_Price = 33.33,    -- not Total_Price?
    Date_of_Submit='2013-04-12 15:34:16',
    Status=1
WHERE OrderID=2
```